# How did they get powers in the first place?

Tags: plot-explanation, moving

In the Korean web series "Moving" (Korean: 무빙), it is mentioned that the children inherit their powers from their parents.

I'm curious about how the parents acquired their abilities in the first place.

Was it through experimentation, or does the series depict a world where some people naturally possess superpowers?

Has there been any explanation provided within the series or by the creators outside of it?